# Text editor install led me to 404 error message when trying to access my wordpress site

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, http-status-code-404, mamp

I am extremely new to this. I have downloaded MAMP and am hoping my local server through this tool with phpMyAdmin. I was moving along just fine, and then I went to install Sublime Text to create a child theme to make customizations to my current wordpress theme. After I copied the file into the Sublime Text tool, I went back to my wordpress site page refreshed and got at 404 error message 'Not Found'. Next, I went into phpMyAdmin and tried to connect to the site from there and got the same message. I can't figure out what happened or how to fix it. This may or may not be a simple fixed but I am totally lost. Please advise.

Thank you,

Kali

Comment: On what platform you have installed Mamp (Mac or PC …)?

Comment: Is your MySQL server still running?